# Write System Call Argument Registers

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86

I have a piece of assembly code which does a [write system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_(system_call)) (is that correct?) via

```
call write@plt
```

Before doing so, the values of `rax`, address `rsp`, `edi`, `rsi` and `rdx` are set/modified.

How do I know which registers are used as arguments for write or system function calls in general?

My guess is that for write it's `rsp`, `edi` and `rsi` since in [`C`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) it takes 3 arguments:

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t nbytes);
```

Comment: Look it up [here](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `call write@plt` you don't *directly* invoke the [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) system call, but a tiny wrapper around that (a tiny C function which does the syscall and sets `errno`  on failure).

So this `write` function is using the standard C [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), defined in the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (application binary interface). For Linux x86-64 read the [SysV ABI interface for x86-64](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf)

Read also [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) to find out a bit more about how some syscalls are actually done. Others might use the `SYSENTER`  machine instruction, etc... Some details are given in the ABI spec (stricto sensu, the real [syscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) is not using any stack and passes arguments & results thru registers). Read also the [Linux Assembly HowTo](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) (more focused on 32 bits x86).

Also, [C standard libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) for Linux are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), generally [GNU glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or perhaps [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/), etc... So study their source code to understand exacty how `write`  is implemented.